# Chromedriver: Thinks my chrome version is different

Tags: linux, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My versions stare that I am on 104

```
[root@artas-conductor-005 ~]# google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 104.0.5112.101
[root@artas-conductor-005 ~]# /usr/bin/google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 104.0.5112.101
[root@artas-conductor-005 ~]#  /usr/bin/chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 104.0.5112.79 (3cf3e8c8a07d104b9e1260c910efb8f383285dc5-refs/branch-heads/5112@{#1307})
```

I get this error though.

```
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 104
E               Current browser version is 88.0.4324.150 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

No idea where it gets version 88 from?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 104
    Current browser version is 88.0.4324.150 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

...implies that though your ***default*** [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) and */usr/bin/chromedriver* version is ***v104.0*** but your tests spins up the *Google Chrome* instance installed within a **customized** location which is still at **v88.0.4324.150**

---

### Solution

You have to update the version of the *Google Chrome* installed in the customised location and used by your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any folder called "chrome" inside working dir, Try to remove it or set chrome path inside your program using `options.setBinary("chromepath");`
and for chromedriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```

**Hope it works**

Comment: The returned message says that the Google Chrome instance is an old one, compared to that of Chromedriver. So, updating Google Chrome (probably both) is the right way to solve it.

Comment: Yep, you're right